# django __class__ method not working on m2m relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In my django project at a instance I need class name of object by its reverse relationship, for that I used `__class__` method .

This is working fine with OneToOne relationship that is

```
print(instance.content_object.__class__)
```

and output is -

```
<class 'products.models.ProductCreateModel'>
```

but when using it with m2m it gives me

```
print(instance.product_seller.__class__)
```

and output is -

```
<class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager'>
```

How can I get the class name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because product_seller isn't an instance of the seller class, it's a [`RelatedManager` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) that manages access to a set of objects from your model.  Try `instance.product_seller.model` to get the class of objects in that set.